# Putting a Perl variable in awk command

Tags: perl, sed

In Perl, I'm trying to search a txt file for a string that the user inputs and print out every line that where the string is found.

Here is what I have

```
my $input = <STDIN>;
print `sed -n "/$input/p" inputfile.txt`;
```

I'm getting this error: 
sed -e expression #1, char 9: unterminated address regex

Could anyone help me out with this?

Comment: The best help would be not to use sed inside Perl. Perl can do that easily.

Comment: Also, that might feel like a neat trick to do, but it is very dangerous. You are allowing users to execute arbitrary code on your system. (E.g. use `"; rm -rf /` as input.) Even if you trust them, things can happen by mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't shell out to sed to do what Perl can do for you.

```
my $input = <STDIN>;
chomp $input;
open my $fh, '<', 'inputfile.txt' or die $!;
while ( <$fh> ) {
    print if /$input/;
}
```

Comment: Hmm.. I tried this and I'm getting no result when I enter something to search. No errors but no result too.

Comment: @JimDavis Yup, you're right lol. Thank you. I'm just learning scripting languages and they're so much more of a pain than learning Java or C++.